# symfony 3.3 DoctrineMongoDBBundle error when generate documents

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, symfony-3.3

I install DoctrineMongoDBBundle in symfony 3.3. I follow the symfony document
http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html
I create a document then I run this command  bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents but I got an error
"Bundle AppBundle does not contain any mapped documents.Did you maybe forget to define a mapping configuration". I check my namespace and It was correct and my configuration file is like symfony document page

Comment: SF33 was released same day ago. Is any info in documentation that DoctrineMongoDBBundle ready to SF33? Do you try do it on sf32 ?

Comment: document is about SF3 . ّI can not find any document or tutorial about SF33 and mongodb

Comment: I just tested the Doctrine-MongoDB example with Symfony 3.3. It works. The error that you got means that Symfony cannot find your document class. Is your document class in the correct directory? It must be located in `src/AppBundle/Document` Attention: It's Document and not Document**s**!